# Facebook Like Button (Social Plugins) No Longer Work?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

I haven't been able to get the facebook Like button to function on my Wordpress site in like the last 2 years. I casually run this and every once in a while I try to revisit this. I've tried a few plugins as well as just manually adding the snippets (Javascript and iFrame versions) and it seems like there have been some changes over the last few years in browser security that have made this a problem for a lot of users. I've tried the 'ambient-light-sensor' security suggestion (I don't even know what that is) that I've read about. I've also tried removing all plugins to see if there is a conflict. No dice. Something has changed over the years on the fb side and/or client side and I just don't have the time to figure this out.

Anyway, I used to be a front and back end web developer and it's been a long time so I'm just looking for a solution otherwise I'll just remove the Like button and call it a day.

Here's an example page (which happens to have 1 like at the moment)
https://www.thatsongsoundslike.com/2023/10/21/goldfinger-superman-vs-green-day-basket-case/